# Run vite + express concurrently with capacitor

Tags: express, vite, capacitor

I have a vite frontend react app with an express api using the vite-express package.

`"dev": "nodemon -w src/server -x tsx src/server/index.ts",`

`"start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production tsx src/server/index.ts",`

Works fine in a browser and runs on android if I run the server on my laptop and add the url to the capacitor config.
I assume the api does not work otherwise because the server does not get started on the android device. Is it possible to run them both on a mobile device?